# Problemas com Alinhamento CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

estou estudando css3 porem estou com dificuldades quanto o alinhameto

meu CODE HTML

```
<body>
    <header class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="checkbox-conteiner">
          <div class="checkbox-wreapper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
            <label class="checkbox" for="toggle">
              <div class="trace"></div>
              <div class="trace"></div>
              <div class="trace"></div>
            </label>
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <nav class="menu-items">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1>Ivan Yanez</h1>
      <h2>Front End e Java Developer</h2>
      <div class="social-media">
        <a
          href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ivan-yanez-38b0b4126/"
          target="_blank"
          >Linkedin</a
        >
        <a href="#">Github</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card-text">
          O objetivo de aprensentar meu Github é para que clientes(técnico)
          possam verificar e analisar meu codigo afim para tomada de decisão
          sobre a aptidão para determinados projetos.
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <h2 class="github-logo">Github</h2>
            <p>Veja os Projetos</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <h2 class="linkedin-logo">Linkedin</h2>
            <p>Acompanhe minha Carreira!</p>
            <div class="card-text-1">
              Ao entrar aqui você poderá visualizar meu Linkedin ainda está em
              processo de melhora e desenvolvimento da mesma espero que em breve
              esteja pronta.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Meu CSS

```
.linkedin-logo {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  right: -10%;
  height: 110%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 00.3s;
}

.github-logo {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 600px;
  right: -20%;
  height: 110%;
  top: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 00.3s;
}

.card-text {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

.card-text-1 {
  width: 90%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
  position: relative;
  right: -120%;
}
```

eh preciso colocar o Escrito GITHUB acima da imagem porem ela não está subindo de jeito nenhum
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, tente colocar um `margin-bottom` ou modificar o seu `margin` do `.github-logo` para `margin: 0 0 20px 0;` tente para ver se muda em algo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda , eu mexi na margin não do meu elemento Logo porem do meu Card ai funcionou .